# Coding a Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I´m trying to made an app which shows a first layout for 5 seconds and after going to the index layout (Home).
The first layout shows only a logo and the name of the app...

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    SystemClock.sleep(5000);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

If I comment the `SystemClock.sleep(5000); Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class); startActivity(i);`, app works as I expected. Show the first layout, staying in this layout (obviously, I´m not launching anything else :P). But, If I descomment them, the activity wait for 5 seconds without showing anything (blank layout).

Any ideas?

Thanks guys.

Comment: Use Handler. postDelayed

Comment: It's working ugly. Why you need Handler? Use View's queue!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show a splash screen on your app you should not show a layout, try to put the main thread to sleep for 5 seconds and the wake the app again. The "right" way (there's no right way of showing a splash screen, as splash screens are almost forbidden on mobile apps) of showing a splash screen would be create a new Activity or Fragment that holds this screen and, using a Handler.postDelayed inside this activity, wait for 5 seconds and then show your main activity.

Useful information on Splash Screens:

https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks. But for my pourpose I prefer Petrov choice. I can decide how low user is waiting. Even I can show animations as well. But, thanks again, it will be useful in the future...

Answer (score 2):

Don't force a wait time in your apps to show a Splash Screen, you are wasting user time. To do a splash screen in the right way you can use the `windowBackground` option from your app theme. Here is an example: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Comment: Thanks. But for my pourpose I prefer Petrov choice. I can decide how low user is waiting. Even I can show animations as well. But, thanks again, it will be useful in the future...

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for something like Splash Screen, which it shows for few seconds and the main activity starts?

Well than you can use something like this:

```
public class ActivitySplash extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_splash);
    Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);

    starter();
}

//Thread for the timer with 3.5 secs.
private void starter()
{
    Thread timer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                //Sleep for 5 seconds.
                sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                //Call and start the new Activity
                Intent newActivity= new Intent(ActivitySplash.this, YOURACTIVITY.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}
}
```

to show a logo in the layout, just make a xml with a logo in center with name you want to enter. here is the one I use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  tools:context=".ActivitySplash">

  <ImageView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/imageView"
     android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this way..

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }, 5000);
```

instead if

```
SystemClock.sleep(5000);
```

Comment: Well, you don't need Handler for that.

Comment: Thanks vrund. It works. I needed only change:
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Home.class);
startActivity(i);

Comment: glad to hear that.. Accept if you feet it is correct answer.

Comment: Well, it wasn´t my correct answer. I prefer Petrov´s choice, it fixes better with my intent. Anyway, it is a correct answer as well. I rated it from the very beggining.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create handlers and threads, which are not necessary!
Your task could be done in this way:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                 //start activity here
            }
        }, 500);
```

Do not create more garbage for your Garbage Collector.

Although, you should mention ActivityTransition's. It that really you are looking for? If not, you could simple add to your layout splash view, which would overlay all contents, and you could play custom animations on this splash view. For example:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             // splash would disappear after 400 ms
             mSplashView.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(400).start();
        }
    }, 500);
```

Comment: It works as well. And I like your approach. Avoid to create garbage... Thanks Petrov